# How to log MySQL ERRORs using bat-file

Tags: mysql, winapi, error-logging

I run bat-file in Windows to clean MySQL Data Base at night.
bat-file just use sql-script with simple delete-where operators.

code in bat-file like : "date /T >> cleaner_front.log" 
log some useful info to output file

code in script.sql file like : SELECT '14. delete from table (7 days)' AS '*_*';  SELECT NOW();
log some useful info too.

But if script.sql contains some errors (like table doesn't exists), error-message (ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 56: Table '...' doesn't exist) was not written to output file

How can I write error messages from MySQL to common cleaner_front.log file during execution?

Answer (score 2):

here is the launch string with error logging:

"path\to\mysql.exe" --host=host --user=user --password=pass -N -f < cleaner.sql  1> cleaner.log 2> cleaner_err.log

Comment: Well looks like the poster didn't appreciate your help - but I do. Thanks.